# Where can be defined a custom IP for a host on Win10 (not in etc\hosts)

Tags: windows, dns

I can not figure out why host name davno.pw is on 127.0.0.1 for my local workstation.
The site is up and running on 5.45.126.52 and its okay
But locally I only see that the name points to 127.0.0.1
And nothing about it in the hosts file:
c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
(the only uncommented line is `127.0.0.1 localhost`)
and at the same time

```
> ping davno.pw

--- PING davno.pw [127.0.0.1] 32 bytes of data. ---
Reply from 127.0.0.1: 32 bytes time<1ms TTL=128
```

It might be some heritage of Open server but I have no idea where the configuration is.

Comment: Check the dns server you are using to resolve. Try some open DNS servers eg. 8.8.8.8 or 1.1.1.1

Comment: Does not help (changed DNS servers and flushed local dns cache)

Comment: check if you are using any proxy. eg. squid ?